# After reading docx file, I want to insert the data in MySQL?

Tags: java

After reading docx file, I want to insert the data in different rows by dividing line by line.

For Example, I have four sentences in my docx file. I want to insert these 4 sentences in 4 rows. How we can do this?

Please send me the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
String text = jTextfield1.getText()
```

and then use some persistence technology: JDBC, or an ORM (JPA). You need a data layer for better design. The simplest is JDBC, but put it in another class.